# Django Compare passwords with Bcrypt

Tags: python, django, bcrypt

I have a problem with bcrypt... How I compare the String saved in the db with the String from the user input

```
this:
>>> import bcrypt
>>> salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
>>> hashed = bcrypt.hashpw('secret', salt)
>>> hashed.find(salt)
0
>>> hashed == bcrypt.hashpw('secret', hashed)
True
>>>
```

and this doesn't work at least I save my passwords raw in the db -_-

Somebody know how to do it?

Comment: I get the answer from "https://pub.dev/documentation/bcrypt/latest/":

Comment: hashpw => to hash /// checkpw => to compare